# Django: Unique IDs for each sub-model of a Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm fairly new to Django, but I believe my question is more towards designing databases regardless of the framework or platform.

Let me explain using following quick pseudo. I have following two models:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=Status.choices, default=Status.OPEN)
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
    text = models.TextField()
    ...
```

In my web app, I'm building a collection of `Issues`. Each issue is assigned a django's auto-generated unique ID number (pk), which is perfect. And for each issue there is a property `comments` which holds a collection of comments specific to this issue.

Each comment also has a system-generated unique ID, but the sequence of this ID is not specific to the Issue model. Means if I create 3 comments in Issue #1 (comment #1, #2, #3), and then I create a comment under Issue #2, that comment's ID is set as #4 instead of #1.

I understand that this is the way the data models are defined. What I would like to have is that whenever a new issue is created and a comment added, its ID should start from `1`. I cannot define comment IDs manually by incrementing over the previous comment ID because the web app will allow users to delete the comments too. So if there are 3 comments under an issue and the last comment #3 is deleted, the next time a comment is added it should be given a unique ID #4.

Any suggestions how do I go about implementing a robust solution to this? TIA

EDIT: The purpose of restarting comment ID from 1 each time is that the comment ID is to be displayed in the HTML against each comment. It will be used by the users for referencing purpose.

Comment: Is there any use for each issue's comments to start at 1?

Comment: @pppig The comment's ID is to be displayed on the html, it will be used for user's referencing purpose (.e.g. "please refer comment #3 on Issue #1)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Give this a try

```
{% for comment in issue.comments.all %}
    No: {{ forloop.counter }}
    {{ comment.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update:**

to fix re-numbering on the deletion of a comment, the best thing you can do is to perform a [soft-deletion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soft_deletion)

```
{% for comment in issue.comments.all %}

    {% if comment.is_active %}
        No: {{ forloop.counter }}
        {{ comment.text }}
     {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

add an `is_active` boolean filed to the Comment model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

then instead of deleting the Comment object, set `is_active` to `False`, which will prevent renumbering issues in the template

Comment: The comment's ID will be displayed on the html, will be used by the users for referencing purpose. So if a comment is deleted from the middle of the collection, the forloop will renumber the IDs for the comments.

Comment: This is perfect. Soft-deletion will definitely solve the problem, that way my comment sequence number won't be affected. Thanks, greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is probably something a bit different. I would add some kind of hierarchy filed to the **Comment** model. (and not play around with the Django auto generated id's).

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
    text = models.TextField()
    hierarchy = models.IntegerField() 
...
```

This way the comments by id will look like this:

1. Issue1 - C1, C2, C3 ... C1-h1, C2-h2, C3-h3 (where h is the hierarchy)
2. Issue2 - C4, C5, C6 ... C4-h1, C5-h2, C6-h3.

This way you will be able to show on the frontend the hierarchy (not the id), and when you will delete a comment (you mentioned this), you will be able to continue with h4. (by my understanding this was your intended purpose).

Let me know if I should clarify more.

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting, and you've correctly understood my query. How will I be able to continue with h4 when a new comment is added? the `hierarchy` doesn't look like an auto-generated field. Are you implying that i have to manually define the h4 to it?

Comment: @FarazAzhar The way I would do it is: 


1. When a comment is created, check if there are other comments linked to that issue. (You could do this with issue.comment_set.all() (for example)
2. If there are no comments, create one with hierarchy 1.
3. If there are, order them by hierarchy and grab the latest, then.. create a new Comment model instance with hierarchy of the latest +1. 
Note: when you delete a comment, don’t delete it from the DB, have like a status that you can set to 'DELETED' or something like that. That way you can keep track of hierarchical ordering.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to keep track of the number of comments per issue. This can be done using `Issue.comments.count()` or use a cached property that is updated every time there is a new comment. If you want to know the order in which the comments were added, you can add a `created_at` field and use it for ordering in your queries as follows `issue.comments.order_by('created_at')`.

Comment: No, not trying to count them. I can count them using the `count()` that's no problem. The comment's ID is to be displayed on the html, it will be used for user's referencing purpose (.e.g. "please refer comment #3 on Issue #1)".

Answer (score 0):

add created_at datetimeField in comment table and sort by created_at to return query

Comment: Need to display the comment's ID number in the html template.

Comment: Like pointed out above: query the number of comments with date before the comment you want to display and use that number as id by adding it to the context for html rendering. If you want to keep ids then add a field in Comment and store the id upon creation of the new comment